# Why And how to use static readonly modifier in C#

Tags: c#, static

Well I was been studying about Destructor, which influenced me to constructors once again ...
So started some googling and testing than I faced something like this ..

```
public class Teacher
{
    private static DateTime _staticDateTime;
    private readonly DateTime _readOnlyDateTime;
    /*Resharper telling me to name it StaticReadolyDateTime insted of _staticReadolyDateTime*/
    private static readonly DateTime StaticReadolyDateTime;

    static Teacher()
    {
        _staticDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        /*ERROR : Thats oke as _readOnlyDateTime is not static*/
        //_readOnlyDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        StaticReadolyDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Teacher()
    {
        _staticDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        _readOnlyDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        /*Error : Why there is an error ?*/
        StaticReadolyDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I made three private attributes of static, readonly, static readonly

As they are private attributes I named them with _prefix. 
But my resharper telling me to rename _staticReadolyDateTime into StaticReadolyDateTime (i.e. as it is static readonly, may be).
Is it oke with the naming convensions ?

on the other hand I am unable to use the static readonly attribute in public constructor, but using that static and readonly one easily.(i.e. even using it in static constructor)

than i googled to find out more, most of them are saying static readonly should only used in static constructor but not saying why ?

so I need to know some usages of static readonly modifier and its best uses and limitations.
Difference with const, static, readonly will be even better ... :)

Comment: It probably says that it can only be *modified* during static construction, not that can only be used during static construction.

Comment: Side note: `public`, `static` are not "attributes", but rather [modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tcf2h8w(v=vs.110).aspx). `public`, as well as `private` and `protected` are [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.110).aspx) . [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287992(v=vs.71).aspx) in C#/.Net are completely different concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-static readonly member can only be set in the class or a non-static constructor.

A static readonly member can only be set in the class or a static constructor.

Hence, it is illegal to set a static readonly member in your non-static constructor. Note that there is nothing wrong with *reading* the static readonly member anywhere you want in the class; the restriction is just on where you can *write* it. If you don't want the restriction, don't call it `readonly`.

Comment: oke ... but why sould use this static readonly fields then ...?

Comment: @DiponRoy - if you can stick to never use static you'd be much better off... But sometimes it is nice to have some computed string value that will never change over lifetime of the process/AppDomain (like `VersionOfSomeFile`).

Answer (score 0):

readonly can be set only in constructor. Once set, it acts like a constant which cannot be modified.
And for static readonly it needs to be set in static constructor.